# How an error message can be shown when barcodes are not recognized by RNcamera ( react-native-camera)

Tags: react-native-camera

I am new to React-native. I have a requirement for barcode scanning and I am using react-native-camera for this. I want to show error message to the user when the barcodes are not recognized for some reason. 
This is code.

```
class Scan extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.barocode = this.barocode.bind(this);}

barocode(e)
{
  if(typeof (e) == 'undefined') // tried this if barcodes are not recognized. This doesn't work.
  {
    alert("error");
  }
  else{
  this.camera.pausePreview();
  alert(e.data);
  }

}


render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RNCamera
          ref={ref => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style = {styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
          onBarCodeRead={(e) => {
            this.barocode(e)}}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

OnbarcodeRead will call the function this.barocode(e) once it recognizes the barcode. This code is working fine for almost all barcodes types listed in the documentation.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-camera.

OnbarcodeRead will be undefined if barcodes are not recognized (this won't call the function this.barocode(e)).I want to show an error message that time. Could anyone guide me the way it can be done.

Comment: have you tried something yourself?

Comment: May you want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @farhana yes , I tried . I have a written a function that would be called when barcodeRead of RNcamera has the data. This works for almost all barcodes types. But there are some barcodes where barcodeRead won't trigger the function attached for it. I read the documentation and it says barcodeRead doesn't do anything if it undefined. So, I want to popup an error message that time saying barcode not detected. Any help for that.